# What is equivalent of the asterisk (*) in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Does anyone know how can I replace the "comment_author_url" field from all comments?

```
UPDATE `comments` 
SET `comment_author_url` = REPLACE(`comment_author_url`, 'http://*.com','http://new.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

The percentage sign (wildcard operator) % is what you are after.
Ps. the 'star' is called an 'asterisk'. :)

Comment: By asterisk ;) I mean to find all strings old1.com, old2.com older3.com and replace with one new.com

Comment: @NikiDrfgheha You would use `http://%.com` to get everything with `http://` and `.com` either side.